# How to show interstitial Ad only once in an activity throughout App session

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

(My problem is when i comeback to the same activity i dont want show again an ineterstitial Ad.I want to show interstitial Ad only once throught the app session.) currently i'm using the default interstitial Ad code given by google admob.

```
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_id));
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
                else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }


        }




    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep a static boolean variable. Once you load the app, make sure to set the boolean variable to false. Once the ad is loaded you can set it to true. When you exit the app make sure to set it back to false(since app process may not get destroyed as soon as you exit the app)

```
    public static isAdLoadedOnce = false;
    ----------------------------------------------

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_id));
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

                if (!isAdLoadedOnce & mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                    isAdloadedOnce = true;
                }
                    else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Actually i have an patch for doing that,We will be Using sharedpreferences for that,

1. First thing you have to do is before loading ads just check in sharedpreferences that is ad is already been loaded once?.if not then just load/show ads and set  flag to true.

   ```
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("isAdsLoaded", true);
   editor.commit();
   ```
2. Okay so for Now whenever this activity open it will not load ads again but to load it again when app is killed and opened again we should have to reset flag.
3. To reset flag, In application class we will be setting this flag to false

   ```
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("isAdsLoaded", false);
   editor.commit();
   ```

Here Application class is the class which one be called every time you opened apps.I hope you know how to create it and mention in manifest file.and if you donn't please comment i will explain it in brief.

Comment: hiii, Thanks for your response. I have Created Application class. But how to check whether the Ad is shown or not? . i am getting error at editor.putBoolean(isAdsloaded,true); //cannot resolve symbol isAdsLoaded. iam very poor in developing.i am at my starting stage.plz help!!

Comment: it should be as key like 

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isAdsLoaded", false);
editor.commit();

Comment: oop's sorry i haven't seen that. but iam getting this error     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.xxxxx.xxxx.ActivityOffline: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences.edit()' on a null object reference

Comment: thank you so much Maulik Togadiya. Problem resolved.

Comment: Okay,Good You Welcome :)